# How to perform two way repeated measures analysis on time series data?

Tags: r, time-series, anova, repeated-measures

I have a dataframe which has `SUBJECT_ID`, `VISIT_NAME` and `BIOMARKER` measurement levels and `ARM_GROUP` as the four columns. The visit names has three levels - visit 1, visit 2 and visit 3. Subjects fall into two groups - cases and controls.

The study is unbalanced.

The objective is to find if there are any differences in the biomarker measurements between the 3 visits and the 2 groups. This calls for a repeated measures ANOVA.

The R code I use for this:

```
anova = aov(BIOMARKER~VISIT_NAME*ARM_GROUP + Error(SUBJECT_ID) , data = studyData)
```

Now, the output from R looks like this:

```
Error: SUBJECT_ID
                                      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
ARM_GROUP                             1     29    29.1   0.074  0.786
VISIT_NAME                            2   1220   610.0   1.551  0.214
ARM_GROUP:VISIT_NAME                  2    945   472.7   1.202  0.302
Residuals                             269 105790   393.3               

Error: Within
                                      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
VISIT_NAME                            2   2182  1091.2  13.759 2.54e-06 ***
PLANNED_ARM_DESC:VISIT_NAME           2    175    87.4   1.102    0.334    
Residuals                             198  15703    79.3                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This is confusing because `Error (SUBJECT_ID)` contains variables from within subjects analysis also. Is this because the study is unbalanced? What will be the correct way to approach this problem?